# increment session

Tags: php, session, increment

I have a login page. when the username or password is right, you go to homepage. but after 3 times you enter wrong user name and password, you go to another page (not homepage).
I start a session in login page.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['login_time']=' ';
```

After checking the user name and password, I want to increment that session, if it is lower than 4 stay in login page:

```
session_start();
if ($_SESSION["login_time"] != null){
    $_var = (int)$_SESSION["login_time"] +1;
    $_SESSION["login_time"] = $_var;
 }
if($_SESSION['login_time']<4){
    header('Location: loginpage.php');  
}
```

But my session doesn't increment and always stays 1. please help.

Comment: You should put `session_start()` only in the beginning so from the second piece of code you should remove the `session_start()` rest all is fine i think

Comment: where is $_SESSION["login_time"]  defined?

Comment: this two parts of codes are in the separate php pages.

Comment: $_SESSION['login_time']='';  instead of 
$_SESSION['login_time']=' ';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    session_start();
 //if login_time is not set, set it to 0   
    if(!isset($_SESSION["login_time"]))
        $_SESSION["login_time"] = 0;
    else
        $_SESSION["login_time"] += 1;
//else increase login_time

//if user did not exceed max tries redirect to loginpage again. 
    if($_SESSION['login_time']<4)
        header('Location: loginpage.php');  
    else
        header('Location: comelater.php');
//else send to comelater.php
```

Pay attention, that if user exceed tries, he won't be able to view page you wrote this code in, until session is over.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
session_start();
if ($_SESSION["login_time"] == null) $_SESSION["login_time"] = 0;
$_SESSION["login_time"] += 1;
if($_SESSION['login_time']<4){
    header('Location: loginpage.php');  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the session is set by using PHP `isset()` not by checking if its not equal to null.

```
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['login_time'])) {
    $_var = (int) $_SESSION['login_time'] + 1;
    $_SESSION['login_time'] = $_var;
} else {
    $_SESSION['login_time'] = 0;
}

if ($_SESSION['login_time'] < 4) {
    header('Location: loginpage.php');  
}
```